# How to plot 3 y-axes plot on plotrix or ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I would like to plot the values as in below example in a three Y-axes and one X-axis plot:

```
Name Replication ratio Growth rate Abundance(%)
Bin1      1.3             4.45       45
Bin2      1.2             5.66       12  
Bin3      1.1            16.34       15 
Bin4      1.5            11.45       3
Bin5      1.5             1.34       2
Bin6      1.9             2.37       32
```

The 'replication rate' and 'growth rate' data should appear as (differentially) colored bar plots whereas abundance data should appear as a line+dot plot on the same plot. In total there would be one X axis and three Y-axes. Any piece of R code would be highly appreciated and would certainly make my day!

Comment: Sorry that my copy-pasted text do not appear in the correct format. Just so that I'm clear: The 4 column headers in the data sheet are 'Name', 'Replication ratio', 'Growth rate', and 'Abundance(%)'. The first data entry corresponding to these 4 column headers goes like this: 'Bin1', '1.3', '4.45' and '45'. Thanks!

Comment: Please take a look on this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to know how to generate a reproducible example

Comment: I would strongly recommend just making three panels with aligned x-axes.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try `plotly`. I had little experience with it myself. This is what I have tried, just to give you some ideas to start with:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(data = df) %>% 
  add_lines(x = ~Names, y = ~Replication, 
            color = I("red"), name = "name01") %>% 
  add_markers(x = ~Names, y = ~Growth, yaxis = "y2", 
              color = I("blue"), name = "name02") %>%
  add_bars(x = ~Names, y = ~Abundance, yaxis = "y3", 
           color = I("purple"), name = "name03") %>%
  layout(
    yaxis = list(showline = TRUE, side = "left", color = "red",  title = "Replication rate"),
    yaxis2 = list(showline = TRUE, overlaying = "y", anchor = "free", color = "blue", title = "Growth rate"), 
    yaxis3 = list(showline = TRUE, side = "right", overlaying = "y", color = "purple", title = "Abundance"),
    xaxis = list(showline = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, dtick = 1, title = ""), 
    showlegend = FALSE, 
    margin = list(pad = 50, b = 90, l = 150, r = 90),
    legend = list(orientation = "h")
```

data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Names = c("Bin1", "Bin2", "Bin3", "Bin4", "Bin5", "Bin6"), 
  Replication = c(1.3, 1.2, 1.1,1.5,1.5,1.9), 
  Growth = c(4.45, 5.65, 16.34, 11.45, 1.34, 2.37), 
  Abundance = c(45, 12, 15, 3, 2, 32)
)
```

[image]

Comment: This is definitely better than you could do with `ggplot2`. But I think it also demonstrates that it is not an effective visualization.

Comment: @Axeman Yes, I can see your point while also can see the potential use of it.

Comment: Many thanks for this idea Zhiqiang Wang- much appreciated!